# @Override in java

Tags: java, overriding

Let's say I got the following, I would even call it pseudo-code

```
public class someClass { 

  public someClass{
    example("Hello Stackoverflow");
  }

  @Override
  public void example(){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }

  public void example(String Hello){
    System.out.println(Hello);
  }
}
```

In this code the method `public void example(String Hello)` would be called instead of the `public void example()` method. How is the compiler working in this case ? The compiler has to decide which method to call in this case, because they got the same name. Is there something like an order e.g. **first try @Override method, if that's not working go for the normal one**. Or how does that work ?

Comment: I think you're confusing **overloading** with **overriding**.

Comment: You pass a `String` parameter and there is only 1 method that takes a `String` parameter? Also you are not overriding anything.

Comment: Compiler will look at the `method name` and method name consists of name of the method in your case it is example and parameters which are passed to your method.`So while you call the compiler would decide which example version would call based on your inputs.This is an example of OVERLOADING`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@Override` annotation tells the compiler: "*Please fail to compile me unless I'm [overriding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding) an existing method defined in a parent class or an interface I implement.*"

However, you are doing [***method  overloading***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) - i.e. methods with the same name but different arguments.

Consequently, your code won't compile because your `example()` method doesn't *override* a method in a parent class or interface. Instead, it overloads another method in the same class. There is no annotation for that.

An example of a valid override would be adding a `toString()` method to your class, which would override the method declared in the `Object` class:

```
public class someClass { 

  public someClass{
    example("Hello Stackoverflow");
  }

  public void example(){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }

  public void example(String Hello){
    System.out.println(Hello);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Hello, World!";
  }
}
```

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that `@Override` is only valid on implementations of interface methods in Java 1.6+

Comment: Nice links by the way

Answer (score 4):

No, what you've shown isn't *overriding* at all - it's *overloading*. (The use of the `@Override` annotation is obviously to do with overriding, but it's incorrect used here - there's no superclass method to override.)

Overriding is when a method signature is declared in a superclass, and then overridden in a subclass (with the same signature). The method implementation is chosen at execution time based on the execution-time type of the object you call it on.

Overloading is when more than one method is present with the same name, but different signatures. When invoking the method, the correct signature is picked at *compile time* based on the compile-time types of the arguments to the method.

For example:

```
public void foo(int x) {}
public void foo(String y) {}
public void foo(Object o) {}
public void foo() {}


foo(50); // Calls the first method
foo("hello"); // Calls the second method
// Calls the third method, because the compile-time type of the argument is
// Object, even though it's actually a reference to a string at execution time
foo((Object) "hello");
foo(); // Calls the fourth method
```

Comment: "The method implementation is chosen at execution time based on the execution-time type of the object you call it on." what do you mean by that ?

Comment: @IbrahimApachi I'd suggest you read up on the subject a little more. Comment threads won't be a great place to get clarity on a broad subject like this.

Comment: Okay :P I will do that

Answer (score 2):

Because you are calling a function with a parameter

```
example("Hello Stackoverflow");
```

that is function overloading study about overloading [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17951/Function-Overloading)

This has nothing at all to do with the `@Override` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing at all to do with the `@Override` annotation.

You can **overload** methods: having more than one method with the same name but different types and number of parameters.

The compiler will choose the method with the signature that matches best (the exact rules are a bit complicated since Java5, what with varargs and auto-boxing).

In your case, you call a method with a String parameter.

A method without parameters does not apply, will not be considered.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an `@Override` since you do not `override` a parent method and code will not compile.

This is **overload**.
Here, you have 2 distinct methods. One take a parameter and the other one not.

So it simple:

- when you call method with a parameter, it's the `example(String hello)` which will be called.
- when you call method without a parameter, it's the `example()` method which will be called.

This is not an **override**.